# RTSP Embedded Video Player with IE, Firefox and Chrome Activex

Tags: html, activex, vlc

I'm looking for a video player that supports RTSP that has working activex controls for IE, Firefox and Chrome.

VLC Player works, however, I cannot get Chrome or IE to detect the activex and have a visitor download the controller if they do not have it.

I was able to get Firefox and IE to work with Quicktime, but not Chrome. WMP doesn't seem to like RTSP, or I'm doing it wrong.

Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Sample of my VLC code:

```
<object classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' codebase='http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab' width='440' height='260'>
<param name='movie' value='rtsp://xxx/mpeg4/ch1/main/av_stream'>
<embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' width='440' height='260' target='rtsp://xxx/mpeg4/ch1/main/av_stream'>
</object>
```